# when fitting a dynamic regression model to a TS, what would happen if we first fit a regression model and then fit an ARMA?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima

When fitting a [dynamic regression model](https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html), we fit a model that has exogenous variables and also ARMA variables.

What would happen if we first fit a regression of all exogenous variables, and then fit an ARMA model on the residuals? would it change the model's predictions? then confidence intervals?

(I'm assuming the data are stationary and ignoring differencing for simplicity)

Answer (score 1):

yes it would as your suggested approach is a conditional one whereas correct prediction limits require simultaneous estimation.

Comment: thanks! "it would" what? change the predictions or the confidence intervals or both?

Comment: Both ...............